# Translations appear in the WP Customizer, but not on the website!

Tags: theme-customizer, plugin-polylang

I have a strange issue: I have translated my website into 2 languages with the Polylang plugin. Main language is French, translations EN and ES.
Some strings (like `Read more`, `x Comments`, `No Comments`, etc.) don't appear in the Polylang list of strings and display in English everywhere, so I translated them directly in the `.pot file` and created a FR and ES `.po file` and `.mo file`.
The strange thing is that the translations appear in the Theme Customizer, but not on the actual webpage!!
https://au-rythme-des-enfants.com/
Theme: `Ashe Pro`
Thanks for any help on this!
Gwen

Comment: I'm also wondering how to translate the "Read more" text, which is a dynamic string in the Customizer and seems to override the translations in the pot and mo files. I've asked both the theme support and polylang support about this and the above question, and both say it isn't a problem with them, that I have to ask the the other support (theme/plugin).

Comment: have you edit the files of the theme ? can you try with the free theme "Ashe" to see if you have the same problem ?